# How to print number in triangle pattern using java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to print a number pattern like below

The condition is when user will enter 6 then only first three rows should display and if user enters 3 then only first two rows should display.

```
class Star 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int i,  j;
        for(i=1; i<=6; i++)
        {
            for(j=1; j<i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

```
1
3  2
6  5  4
10  9   8  7
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please read [ask] and format your question appropriately next time.

Comment: What should the program do if the user enters 5?

Comment: Why is your code printing `*` if you want numbers to be printed? What have you tried to actually do this **assignment** for yourself? Because that code is from a different assignment, so it appears you're asking us to do the assignment for you.

Comment: Manish, I suggest you read: [An open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31456).

Comment: Sorry for the inappropriate post. Actually I'm new here    @Pang if user enters 5 then also first three rows should display. I'm tying this assignment for myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have created something like this:

```
/**
 * Created by maciej.brzozowski.83@gmail.com on 2017-04-02.
 */
class Star
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int userValue = 6;
        int counter = 1;

        for(int i=1; i<=userValue; i++)
        {
            for(int j=1; j<i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(counter-j+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
            counter +=i;
        }
    }
}
```

output patern was:

```
1 
3 2 
6 5 4 
10 9 8 7 
15 14 13 12 11
```

I've change a litile bit Your code - I add "counter" and for me it was the easyiest way to achive what You want.
For me alsow You should chane line

```
i<=userValue
```

to

```
i<=userValue+1
```

because user wants to print 6 line but in Your code prints only 5

All comments written in BrokenEnglish :)